# Can't install jupyter (Python 3.9.0, macos 11)

Tags: python, macos, pip, jupyter-notebook, apple-m1

I installed Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64, and tried to pip install --upgrade pip.
But it shows same error message.

The install package command is `pip install jupyter`.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: argon2-cffi
  Building wheel for argon2-cffi (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/dong/miniforge3/bin/python3.9 /Users/dong/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/k3/97_hcf414hdflf7snt870zlc0000gn/T/tmp7zue7y84
       cwd: /private/var/folders/k3/97_hcf414hdflf7snt870zlc0000gn/T/pip-install-fvo3ra87/argon2-cffi_43f8dcc2cf894b4bb48b05d5556d0c5d
  Complete output (29 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9
  creating build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/argon2
  copying src/argon2/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/argon2
  copying src/argon2/low_level.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_ffi_build.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_password_hasher.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/argon2
  copying src/argon2/exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_legacy.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/argon2
  copying src/argon2/__main__.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/argon2
  copying src/argon2/_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/argon2
  running build_clib
  building 'argon2' library
  creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9
  creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras
  creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2
  creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src
  creating build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/blake2
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/argon2.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/argon2.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/blake2/blake2b.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/blake2/blake2b.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/core.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/core.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/encoding.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/encoding.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/ref.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/ref.o
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -fPIC -O2 -isystem /Users/dong/miniforge3/include -arch arm64 -Iextras/libargon2/src/../include -Iextras/libargon2/src/blake2 -c extras/libargon2/src/thread.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/thread.o
  /Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/python-split_1608587737618/_build_env/bin/llvm-ar rcs build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/libargon2.a build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/argon2.o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/blake2/blake2b.o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/core.o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/encoding.o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/ref.o build/temp.macosx-11.0-arm64-3.9/extras/libargon2/src/thread.o
  error: command '/Users/runner/miniforge3/conda-bld/python-split_1608587737618/_build_env/bin/llvm-ar' failed: No such file or directory
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for argon2-cffi
Failed to build argon2-cffi
ERROR: Could not build wheels for argon2-cffi which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Tried many times, but it is still such an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, might help
`pip install jupyter notebook`
Check also [here](https://jupyter.org/install).
I never used Mac, might the proper way is `pip install notebook`

Comment: I tried the method in the URL you gave, and it can be successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest to use Python `3.8.X`, I think it is too early for `3.9.X`, let them fix smth or because it is not yet supported, I need to check that. I usually move to next Python after 3-6 months only.